# How to make mouswheel switch tabs slower in sublimetext

Tags: sublimetext

I searched already for this for some time, but could not find a solution.

I have `mouse_wheel_switches_tabs` set to true, but on my system and with my mouse, when I scroll the minimal amount possible on the mousewheel, already 2 tabs are switched.

Is there a setting to make the amount, that the mousewheel advances (or goes back) in the open tabs smaller?

I do not want to change my mouse settings, because they are already adjusted to everything else.

I believe this should be adjustable, because you can never garanty that on all systems the mouse wheel has a similar pace.

I also tried to set the `scroll_speed` setting to values above or below 1, and also to 0, but this did not change anything.

I am on windows and I am not adding a version number, because I will happily switch to any version that can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse wheel is not something that is calculated in small steps, but rather it has a concrete amount of events fired for each scroll step, thus SublimeText can't do anything but receive 2 steps each time you do a scroll, this is controlled by system or your mouse, but I doubt that your mouse vendor has built a hardware that does fires two steps for this minimum amount.

So I highly doubt it's possible without changing your mouse settings. At least without tweaking the core of SublimeText, which is not possible as it's code is not open-source.

Comment: OK, so you are basically telling me there is no such setting. (If there were such a setting it would be no problem to set it to 1 tab per 2 events)

Comment: No, there is no setting for this, all available settings can be found in your default preferences config file